# A question on differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ be a function differentiable on  [$a,b$] , $f(a)=0$ and there is a real number $A$ such

that $|f'(x)| \le A|f(x)| , \forall x\in$ [ $a,b$] , then how do we prove that $f(x)=0 , \forall x \in$[$a,b$] ?

My Work : Let $M=\sup${ $|f(x)|:x\in$[$a,b$] }and $M_1=\sup${$|f'(x)|:x\in$[$a,b$] } . Then

$M_1 \le AM$ , then by LMVT ,  for $a < x\le b$, $\exists z\in (a,x)$ such that

$|f(x)-f(a)|=|f(x)|=|f'(z)|(x-a) \le M_1(x-a)\le AM(x-a)$ . If we can show $M=0$ we

are done but I cannot proceed further , moreover I am not sure whether $M,M_1$ exists in $\mathbb R$ or not . Please help .Don't use integration I have been told that continuity and differentiation knowledge is enough  .

Comment: $M$ exists (Weierstrass' theorem). We cannot guarantee that $f'$ is continuous, then Weierstrass' theorem is not applicable to $f'$, but $|f'(x)|\leq A|f(x)|\leq AM$. So $M_1$ exists, too.

Comment: You edited your question, adding conditions like "not wanting a solution using integration" after I posted my answer. Do you have a particular solution that you want in mind ?

Answer (score 2):

Let $G(x)=\int_a^x|f(t)|dt$, for $x\in [a,b]$. We have
$$
|f(x)|=\left|\int_a^xf'(t)dt\right|\leq \int_a^x|f'(t)|dt \leq A\int_a^x|f(t)|dt=AG(x)
$$
That is
$$
\forall\, x\in[a,b],\quad G'(x)\leq A G(x).
$$
Now the function $h:x\mapsto e^{-Ax}G(x)$ has a negative derivative on $[a,b]$, so it must
be decreasing. But $h(a)=0$, hence $h(x)\leq 0$ for $x\in[a,b]$. This implies that $h(x)=0$ for $x\in[a,b]$, (because $h$ is clearly nonnegative). In particular $h(b)=0$ or equivalently $G(b)=0$ that is 
$\int_a^b|f(t)|dt=0$. Therefore $f\equiv0$ on $[a,b]$ because $|f|$ is positive continuous.$\qquad\square$

Answer (score 0):

Assume there is $t\in(a,b]$ such that $f(t)\ne 0$, WLOG $f(c)>0$. Since $f$ is continuous then there exists $s\in[a,t)$ with $f(s)=0$ and $f(x)>0,\forall x\in(s,t].$

Now define $g:(s,t)\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ by $$g(x)=\ln f(x)-Ax,\forall x\in(s,t).$$ Note that $g^\prime(x)=\frac{f^\prime(x)}{f(x)}-A\le0,\forall x\in(s,t),$ so $g$ is a non-increasing function on $(s,t)$. Consequently,
$$
0=f(s)=\lim_{x\to s}f(x)=\lim_{x\to s}e^{g(x)+Ax}\ge e^{g(t)+At}=f(t)>0
$$
which is impossible.